# NoSQL Database schema design for simple courses sharing application

Tags: database, database-design, nosql

I am working on a mini-simple app using NoSQL. I currently have the design below and I am seeking practical advice and feedback on the database schema design.

Here is the basic overview of the website: A user can log in (via Google or Github), create a course review, other users can rate this course, give comments and also favorite this course.

Here is the schema design for now:

```
/user
    "userid": "12jdfbvsidf3123"
        "username": "admin"
        "FirstName": "Jobs"
        "LastName": "Tim"
        "email": "123123@123.edu"
        "rated"
            "course1": 2
            "course2" 3
        "favorites":
            "course1_id": 2
            "course2_id" 3
/courses
    "courseid": "sfgsdfwthrw34523"
        "userid": "12jdfbvsidf3123"
        "title": "the Art of Copy and Paste from StackOverflow"
        "instructor": "you-know-nothing"
        "rating": 0
        "introduction": "bla bla bla"
        "timestamp": "2017-08-09"


/comments
    "commentid": "242334h5kjh2j4"
        "userid": "12jdfbvsidf3123"
        "courseid": "sfgsdfwthrw34523"
        "content": "Great course, tell me all about how to copy and paste without thinking"
        "timestamp": "2019-09-07"
```

Comment: I think a key feature of NoSQL is that you can have multiple documents in the same collection with different schemas. Focus on your use cases and then your data model. Just an opinion.

Comment: What is the database that you want to use? NoSQL doesn't say its name. Also there are many different NoSQL databases.